# How can I make Outlook 2007 be quicker when figuring out email addresses?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Normally when I'm sending an email I type in the first part of the recipient's address or their name in the to: line and move on to the subject/email.

Back in the ol' 2003 days Outlook would promptly figure out who I was talking about and substitute the correct email (or at provide visual confirmation that the name was found in the address book) almost immediately.  At least by the time I started writing the body of the email.

2007, however, is SLOW when figuring out email addresses.  In fact, I often find myself waiting to see if it does after finishing my email.  Sometimes I'm already looking up the correct email when outlook finally figures it out by itself.

This is bugging the CRAP outta me!  Is there any way to speed up outlook 2007's email address lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try and send the email it will immediately resolve the names and prompt you when necessary. I'm never sure if it accidentally would send the email to the wrong person.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> will force the email editor to check the names.

If you use the Word editor to write your emails you will want to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>